# How to declare, define, and call a functions in C program which have to 1)"fill" the 3D-array and 2)"read" the 3D-array of characters

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array, reference

I am a novice in C-programming and I need help from anyone who is familiar with 3D-arrays and can perform some changes on them by functions. 
 All explanations, which I found on net, based on 2D-arrays. I can't understand them.

I mean, I understand the basics of pointers, function prototypes(declarations), function definitions, and how to operate with 1D-arrays of data.

I know that any function call can make a local copy or change a variable data in its physical storage, but I can't understand one thing. When you call function with `char *` type parameter(array), you always type it like — `void func_name(char * var_name)` — so, if you need to change the value, you type it in just like that, and when you have not to change — you add `const` before `char * var_name`. 
 For parameters of `int` and `char`-types we have another rule: you have to add (de?)reference operator - `*` - in func prototype and its definition, if you want to change the variable data in storage, and you don't have to use it if there's no need of changing("take local copy" command); and, you have to call a func with dereference operator `&`, applied to parameter — for example `void func_name(&var_name);` , if you have to change the variable data.

Could you please explain how to behave properly when my task is to operate with 3D-arrays by specific functions — "fill the first dimension", "fill the 3rd dimension" "read Nth dimension(local copy)"-commands? How I have to write function prototypes to change and not to change the value of 3D-array?

`void func_name(char *array[][][])` — is that correct?

`void func_name( char *(***array) )` — or maybe like that?

If I have to operate with elements in EACH dimension, do I have to prototype functions like this? :

```
void func_name( char *(*array), char *(**array), char *(***array) ) {. . .}
```

Is there any specific rules for **calling** 3D-array-operating functions? Or I just have to leave them like `func_name(var_name);` ?

I've found some working code, which try to explain how to define a function with 2d-array as a parameter in it and how to call this function which just "reads" the 2d-array(takes local copy).
But this code doesn't make it clear for me how to perform another operation("fill") with functions and how to write prototype properly. And, the example has only operations with `int`-type, but I need `char *`..
The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int M = 3;
const int N = 3;

void print(int arr[M][N])
{
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < M; i++)
      for (j = 0; j < N; j++)
        printf("%d ", arr[i][j]);
}


int main()
{
    int arr[][3] = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
    print(arr);
    char answer[10];
    printf("ok? : ");
    scanf("%s", answer);
    return 0;
}
```

And finally, I can't understand clearly what does these phrases mean: "2d-array of pointers to characters" , "Pointer to 2D-array of characters" ; and I can't understand contexts, where to use "array of pointers" and where to use "pointer to array". 
The mess in my head is grown from the fact, that in function prototypes and definitions we use `(type-name) *` as a type always with array as a function argument.

There are a lot of questions, so I will appreciate any help, thanks!

EDIT 1:

Guys, I've poked around for a while and got some working compilation, which resolves my task. Thanks everyone for the feedback, my solution is below.

Solution:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void find(int a, char *name, char *country, char *city, const char (*paaa)[4][100]);
void fill( char (*paaa)[4][100] );

// --------------------------------------------//
int main()
{
  char name[100] = {0}, country[50] = {0}, city[50] = {0};

  char array3D[100][4][100]; // 0 field is for name, 1 - for city, 2 - for country
  char (*paaa)[4][100] = &array3D[0]; // initialize the pointer 'paaa'

  fill(paaa); // fills 12 entries with the same data in each field

  printf("> full array: \n");
  printf("\033[0;34m"); // set text color to blue
  for (int x = 0; x < 12*4; x++) // each entry contains 4 fields of strings, so '12*4' here
  {
    printf("%s", (*paaa)[x]);
  }
  printf("\033[0m"); // reset text color to default

  int a = 0;
  printf("> input entry number(max:11): ");
  scanf("%u", &a);
  printf("\n");

  find(a, name, country, city, paaa); // retrieve each field in variables

  printf("ENTRY No. %u : \n\n", a);
  printf("> Name - %s\n", name);
  printf("> City - %s\n", city);
  printf("> Country - %s\n", country);
  printf("> Good? : ");
  scanf("%u", &a);
  printf("> Done.\n\n");

  return 0;
}
// --------------------------------------------//


void fill( char (*paaa)[4][100] )
{
    char local_name[50] = { " Jacob Goodman \n" };
    char local_city[50] = { " Melbourne \n" };
    char local_country[50] = { " Australia \n" };

    int entries_amount = 12;
    int en = 0, da = 0; //entry, data

    for (en = 0; en < entries_amount ; en++)
    {

          for ( da = 0; local_name[da] != '\0'; da++)
            {
            paaa[en][0][da] = local_name[da];
            }
          for ( da = 0; local_city[da] != '\0'; da++)
            {
            paaa[en][1][da] = local_city[da];
            }
          for ( da = 0; local_country[da] != '\0'; da++)
            {
            paaa[en][2][da] = local_country[da];
            }

    }
}

// takes an entry number,
// reads from 3D-array 3 fields of given entry
// and saves each field to 3 global variables
void find(int a, char *name, char *city, char *country, const char (*paaa)[4][100])
{
  int da = 0;
  for ( da = 0; paaa[a][0][da] != '\0'; da++)
    {
    name[da] = paaa[a][0][da];
    }
  for ( da = 0; paaa[a][1][da] != '\0'; da++)
    {
    city[da] = paaa[a][1][da];
    }
  for ( da = 0; paaa[a][2][da] != '\0'; da++)
    {
    country[da] = paaa[a][2][da];
    }

}
```

Comment: I would translate "2d-array of pointers to characters" as an array of arrays (the "2d-array part) of pointers to `char`. I.e. an array of arrays of string-pointers, e.g. `char *array[DIM1][DIM2]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A "pointer to T" can be used to point to a single T variable or to point to the first element of an array of T. All elements of the array of T can be accessed via the pointer.

```
T a;
T arr[3];  // Array [3] of T
T *pa = &a; // Pointer to T
T *parr = &arr[0]; // Pointer to T. Equivalent initializer: T *parr = arr;

*pa = foo;     // will set a = foo;
parr[2] = bar; // will set arr[2] = bar;
```

`pa` and `parr` are both of type "pointer to T".

A "2-D array of T" is an "array of array of T":

```
T aa[4][3]; // Array [4] of array [3] of T

aa[0][1] = foo;
```

An "array of pointers to T" can be used to mimic a 2-D array of T. Each pointer element points to its own array of T which could be dynamically allocated as below:

```
T *ad[4]; // Array [4] of pointer to T

for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    ad[i] = calloc(3, sizeof (T));
}

ad[0][1] = foo;
```

A "pointer to an array of T" can be used to access elements of a 2-D array of T:

```
T aa[4][3]; // Array [4] of array [3] of T
T (*paa)[3] = aa; // Pointer to array [3] of T. Equivalent initializer: T (*paa)[3] = &aa[0];

paa[0][1] = foo; // will set aa[0][1] = foo;
```

A "pointer to pointer to T" can be used to access the elements of an "array of pointer to T":

```
T arow0[3], arow1[3], arow2[3], arow3[3]; // Each is array [3] of T
T *ad[4] = {arow0, arow1, arow2, arow3}; // Array [4] of pointer to T
T **pad = &ad[0]; // Pointer to pointer to T. Equivalent initializer: T **pad = ad;

pad[0][1] = foo; // will set ad[0][1] = foo; will set arow0[1] = foo;
```

A "3-D array of T" is an "array of array of array of T":

```
T aaa[4][3][2]; // Array [4] of array [3] of array [2] of T
```

A "pointer to 2-D array of T" is a "pointer to array of array of T", and can be used to access the elements of a 3-D array of T (of compatible dimensions):

```
T aaa[4][3][2]; // Array [4] of array [3] of array [2] of T
T (*paaa)[3][2]; // Pointer to array [3] of array [2] of T

paaa = aaa; // Equivalent: paaa = &aaa[0];
paaa[0][1][1] = foo; // will set aaa[0][1][[1] = foo;
```

A "2-D array of pointers to T" is an "array of array of pointers to T":

```
T arow00[2], arow01[2], arow02[2]; // Each is array [2] of T
T arow10[2], arow11[2], arow12[2];
T arow20[2], arow21[2], arow22[2];
T arow30[2], arow31[2], arow32[2];
T *app[4][3] = {
      {arow00, arow01, arow02},
      {arow10, arow11, arow12},
      {arow20, arow21, arow22},
      {arow30, arow31, arow32}
    }; // Array [4] of array [3] of pointer to T

app[0][1][1] = foo; // Will set arow01[1] = foo;
```

A "pointer to pointer to pointer to T" can be used to access the elements of an array of pointers to pointers to T:

```
T arow00[2], arow01[2], arow02[2]; // Each is array [2] of T
T arow10[2], arow11[2], arow12[2];
T arow20[2], arow21[2], arow22[2];
T arow30[2], arow31[2], arow32[2];
T *parow0[3] = { arow00, arow01, arow02 }; // Each is array [3] of pointer to T
T *parow1[3] = { arow10, arow11, arow12 };
T *parow2[3] = { arow20, arow21, arow22 };
T *parow3[3] = { arow30, arow31, arow32 };
T **ppa[4] = { parow0, parow1, parow2, parow3 }; // Array [4] of pointer to pointer to T
T ***pppa = ppa; // Pointer to pointer to pointer to T;

pppa[0][1][1] = foo;
// will set ppa[0][1][1] = foo;
// will set parow0[1][1] = foo;
// will set arow01[1] = foo;
```

Comment: That is a gold explanation, thank you very much!!! I've got something from it(to get all I need more time..) and made some working code, I've just added it to the topic.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to first leave this whole mess of questions and concentrate on the task you want to do.

You have given several examples for operations with functions, to operate with an three-dimensional array. I will choose the option to fill an array with values by the use of `scanf()` as example.

What i would do is just give a pointer to the 3D array as function argument.

The declaration/prototype for this function would be:

`void fill(char *p);`

Furthermore, i would increase that pointer inside the function, plus use this increased pointer in loops to fill all elements:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int M = 3;
const int N = 3;

int main(void)
{
    char a[M][N];
    fill(a);

    return 0;
}

void fill(char *p)
{
    int i,j;

    for(i = 0, j = 0; i < ( M * N ); i++,j++)
    {
      if(j == M)
      { 
          printf("\n");
          j = 0;
      }

      scanf("%c",(p + i));
    }
}
```

For the other questions, I would recommend that you ask separate questions for each to get more answers and to get an answer which is most appropriate for its special case.

Comment: Do you intend to answer the part of the question having to do with `3D` arrays?  (i.e. for example `char *array[m][n];`

Comment: Worth noting that, while the suggestion compiles in plain C, the argument of the call to fill does not actually match the parameter type.  The matching parameter type is the very peculiar char (*p)[N], which is then not compatible with the existing function body.  Multi-dimension arrays in C are very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Ian Abbott's answer is good.  To summarize a bit, an array name is a pointer to the first member, as always.  But only for one dimension.  So `int a[10]` is an array of `int` and becomes a pointer to `int`, written `int *`. The array `int a[10][20]` is an array of ten arrays of 20 `int`.  It becomes a pointer to an array of 20 `int`, written `int (*)[20]`, but not pointer to pointer to `int`.

You also cannot leave out the extra sizes.  They are part of the type.  If you need to be able to write a function which takes any three-dimensional array, you're sunk.  You can use C++ and make a template.  In plain C, the usual is to declare your array as single-dimension and impose any dimensional structure by doing your own subscript arithmetic.

Comment: Thank you, that's a valuable addition.